# No carga correctamente fa-icon

Tags: html, font-awesome, icono

Estoy utilizando fa-icon, pero a veces cargan de forma incorrecta
[image: Símbolo 1]
[image: símbolos 2 y 3]

Así es como los uso

```
<i class="fa fa-search button-icon" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
<i class="fas fa-user-times"></i>
<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
```

Cuando cargan bien se ven de esta forma
[image: Icono 1]
[image: Iconos 2 y 3]

Cuando se recarga la página se muestran como debe ser, en ocasiones hay que recargar un par de veces más

Comment: Ves algo en la consola del navegador cuando cargas la página? Digamos, algún error en la pestaña network pensando en que algún recurso no cargue? Algún error?

Comment: Puedes poner todo el archivo con la llamada al CDN de los iconos?

Comment: No se muestra ningún error en network

Comment: Por lo regular cuando utilizas CDN requiere de una conexión a Internet estable, de no cargarse correctamente por lo regular muestran una tipografía de error, si descargas los paquetes de dichos iconos en tu proyecto o servidor siempre estarán disponibles, toma en cuenta que algunas librerías manejan iconos de paga. Puede deberse a diversos factores, como te mencionaron revisa la consola del navegador si hay errores.